# Long running processing in handlers with boost::asio

Tags: boost, client-server, boost-asio

I'm designing a network sever based on boost::asio. I need to perform long running processing jobs in handlers and think that these processing should be moved from handlers to separate thread pool where I would have better control (e.g. prioritize tasks). Handlers would just enqueue a new task in job queue.

There would be also a response queue where responses would be dequeued and send back to the clients. (client send requests synchronously)

I wonder if this make sense or just miss something.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is Yes. Long answer it depends. Generally speaking, if you want a higher network though put you should minimize processing that is performed in the handlers and offload it to a thread. This is especially important if you have causality requirements for the data that you receive, since `async_receive` doesn't guarantee execution order of handlers.